# wait for backbone template to be appended to the dom

Tags: backbone.js, asynchronous

I am trying to bind events to elements that are placed by appending a backbone template:

```
 appendEditTemplateAndSetEvents: function() {
                var associatedCollection = App.Helpers.findAssociatedCollection(this.allCollections, this.associatedCollectionId);
                var template = this.setEditTemplateForElement(associatedCollection.type);
                var modalBody = this.$el.find('.modal-body');

                modalBody.empty();

                var firstModel = associatedCollection.at(0);

                if(template.mainTemplate !== null) {
                    modalBody.append($('#edit-form-element-frame').html());

                    //each mode in collection
                    associatedCollection.each(function(model){
                        if(model.get('positionInContainer') === 1) {
                            firstModel = model;
                        }
                        console.log(model.attributes);
                        modalBody.find('.elements-in-editmodal-wrapper').append(template.mainTemplate(model.toJSON()));
                    });
                }

                if( template.templateValidation.length !== 0 ) {
                    modalBody.append('<hr><h3>Validateregels</h3>');
                    _.each(template.templateValidation, function(val, index) {
                        modalBody.append(val(firstModel.toJSON()));
                    });
                }

                //set listeners and handlers that apply when a edit modal is open
                this.validationEventsForEditModal(firstModel);
                this.editErrorMessagesInModal(firstModel);
            },
```

Now the problem is that when the last two functions are called the html of the templates isn't appended yet so the the events are binded to an object with a length of 0.

Does anyone have a decent solution for this async problem? I tried $.Defferred but that did not work, but maybe someone get's it working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `this.$el.find(...)` in the functions:

```
this.validationEventsForEditModal(firstModel);
this.editErrorMessagesInModal(firstModel);
```

I don't know if it's still an async problem, but this solves it.